# Create temporary env variables from .env file

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file with the following:

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=5432
USER_NAME=postgres
```

I also have some commands whose options I want to populate with the environment variables. For example:

```
$(cat ignore/.env | xargs) psql --host=$HOST --port=$PORT --username=$USER_NAME --password
```

This is so I can easily run the commands with different environment vars and also check the commands into version control without any sensitive data. But I am getting the error:

```
HOST=localhost: command not found
```

Comment: With `$(cat ignore/.env | xargs)` you are trying to execute a command named `HOST=localhost` with arguments `PORT=5432` and `USER_NAME=postgres`. It cannot work. What about `source ignore/.env; psql --host=$HOST...` or equivalently `. ignore/.env; psql --host=$HOST...`?

Comment: If you want to limit the scope of your variable definitions you could simply run all this in a subshell: `( . ignore/.env; psql ... )`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet With the brackets that does exactly what I want, thank you!

Comment: Aside from the structurally meaningless command you are posting, I don't see that you would set any environment variable in your code. Please provide a minimal, reproduciable example.

Answer (score 2):

As per @RenaudPacalet 's comments, this works as expected:

```
(. ignore/dev.env; psql --host=$HOST --port=$PORT --username=$USER_NAME --password)
```